# How to get SoapUI request and response XML in java

Tags: java, xml, api, testing, soapui

I'm using the SoapUI API as part of an existing java project. 
The application should save the request and response XML in an specific report file. 
I wonder if it's possible to get those requests and responses via the API. 
The method invoking the TestCaseRunner looks like this

```
protected void checkTestCase(TestCase testCase) {
    TestCaseRunner tr = testCase.run(null, false);
    for (TestStepResult tcr : tr.getResults()) {
         String status = tcr.getStatus();
         String time = tcr.getTimeTaken() + "ms";
        /* How to get XML messages?
         * String request = 
         * String response = 
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on exactly what kind of test steps you have they might be an instance of a MessageExchange. Casting the TestStepResult to a MessageExchange and calling getRequestContent / getResponseContent might do the trick.

```
String request = ((MessageExchange)tcr).getRequestContent();
String response = ((MessageExchange)tcr).getResponseContent();
```

Comment: I am getting this exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.MessageExchange`. Do you have any idea

Comment: You need to iterate through ```runner.getResults()```.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the following way to get the response from the API CAll performed:

```
runner = testRunner.runTestStepByName("Your Test Case name");
// Here we take the response in ms of the API call
timeTaken = runner.response.timeTaken;
// here we get the HTTP response code.
responseCode = runner.getResponseHeaders()."#status#";
// here we get the response content
String response = runner.getResponseContent();
// here we get the API call endpoint -> in case you need to print it out.
String endPoint = runner.getEndpoint();
```

Comment: This is not a valid code `(runner).getResponseContent();`